# Hbase coporcessor connot be loaded the new one?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, hbase

I have created a coprocessor and uploaded it to hdfs. I loaded this coprocessor with alter command for my table,

```
alter 'my:table', METHOD => 'table_att', 'coprocessor$1' => 'hdfs://master/user/coprocessor-1.0.jar|com.xxx.IndexCoprocessor||'
```

But, I modified my program and re-uploaded it to hdfs after deleted old jar file. And then, I unset old coprocessor and loaded new one.

```
alter 'my:table', METHOD => 'table_att_unset', NAME => 'coprocessor$1'
```

I found the new one cannot be loaded correctly, and still loaded the old one, 
just like hdfs cached the old coprocessor?

My hbase vesion is 1.3.1, hdfs is 2.7.2.

Comment: Try to read this https://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/hbase-coprocessors

Comment: I think I have the same problem as you.  And has this bug been fixed? Can you offer me the link about this Jira you raise?